# NoReverseMatch error for update and delete view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-2.2

I've a trouble with an update view and a delete view. Below the code:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.utils.text import slugify

from .forms import BlogTagForm
from .models import BlogTag

def updateBlogTag(request, slug_tag=None):
    update_tag = get_object_or_404(BlogTag, slug_tag=slug_tag)
    form = BlogTagForm(request.POST or None, instance=update_tag)
    if form.is_valid():
        update_tag = form.save(commit=False)
        update_tag.slug_tag = slugify(update_tag.tag_name)
        update_tag.save()
        return redirect('tag_list')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    template = 'blog/editing/create_tag.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def deleteBlogTag(request, slug_tag):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tag = BlogTag.objects.get(slug_tag=slug_tag)
        tag.delete()
    return redirect('tag_list')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class BlogTag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(
        'Tag',
        max_length=50,
        help_text="Every key concept must be not longer then 50 characters",
        unique=True,
        )
    slug_tag = models.SlugField(
        'Slug',
        unique=True,
        help_text="Slug is a field in autocomplete mode, but if you want you can modify its contents",
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_blogtag", kwargs={"slug_tag": self.slug_tag})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['tag_name']
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogTag

class BlogTagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag_name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        help_text="<small>Write a tag here. The tag must be have max 50 characters.</small>",
        widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={
                                "placeholder": "Tag",
                                "type": "text",
                                "id": "id_tag",
                                "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
                                }
                            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = BlogTag
        fields = ["tag_name"]
```

**urls.py**

```
path("update-tag/", views.updateBlogTag, name='update_tag'),
path("delete-tag/", views.deleteBlogTag, name='delete_tag'),
```

**tag_list.html**

```
  <table class="table table-striped shadow">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Tag</th>
        <th>Related Posts</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for tag in tag_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ tag.tag_name }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag.tag_blogpost.count }}</a></td>
        <td>

          <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm mx-1" href="{#% url 'update_tag' slug_tag=tag.slug_tag %#}">Update</a>

            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mx-1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>

            <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title text-center" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Request</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h3>Are you sure to delete this tag?</h3>
                    <h1 class="py-4"><em><strong>{{ tag.tag_name }}</strong></em></h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">No, don't do this</button>
                    <form action="{% url 'delete_tag' tag.slug_tag %}" method="POST">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" name="button">Yes, delete it</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
      </tr>

      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I've used the same type of code for another views without problems but in this case I've this error:

> **UPDATE VIEW** NoReverseMatch at /blog/tags/
>
> Reverse for 'update_tag' with keyword arguments '{'slug_tag':
>   'altro-tag'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/update\-tag/$']
>
> **DELETE VIEW** NoReverseMatch at /blog/tags/
>
> Reverse for 'delete_tag' with arguments '('altro-tag',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried: ['blog/delete\-tag/$']

I don't understand where is the error in my code. Someone can tell me where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming because you haven't added angle brackets to capture your slug while constructing your URL. I assume your URL looks like this `url(r'blog/update-tag/$', updateBlogTag(), name='updated_tag')` and `url(r'blog/delete-tag/$', deleteBlogTag(), name='delete_tag')` they should look like this instead `url(r'blog/update-tag/<slug:slug_tag>/$', updateBlogTag(), name='updated_tag')` and `url(r'blog/delete-tag/<slug:slug_tag>/$', deleteBlogTag(), name='delete_tag')` [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: Yes, you are right. What a stupid error! When I've writed the paths I'm lost the angle brackets. Consider that there are in the two paths for the same action for the blog posts!